# Paramaterization of paraboloid and plane.

Tags: calculus, 3d, parametric

Consider the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$.  The plane $2x-4y+z-6=0$ cuts the paraboloid, its intersection being a curve.  Find "the natural" parameterization of this curve.

I have set each equation equal to each other by solving for $z$, completed the square to reach $(x-1)^2+(y+2)^2=11$.  This is where I am stuck.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugging $z=x^2+y^2$ into $2x-4y+z-6=0$ we get
\begin{align*}
2x-4y+x^2+y^2-6&=0\\
x^2+2x+\color{red}{1}+y^2-4y+\color{red}{4}&=6+\color{red}{1+4}\\
(x+1)^2+(y-2)^2&=11
\end{align*}

Then, a parameterization for the curve is 
$$\begin{cases}x&=\sqrt{11}\cos t-1 \\ y&=\sqrt{11}\sin t+2\\z&=2\sqrt{11}(2\sin t -\cos t)+16\end{cases}\qquad 0\le t\le 2\pi$$